# How to put text view in the center of the layout if second Textview visibility is gone?

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

How to put text view in the center of the layout if second Textview visibility is gone?

I have attached a layout that I draw by hand.

I have there two Textview inside lets say ConstraintLayout

I want to write an xml that in situation that there are two visible TextViews sets margin and constraint according to numbers in screenshot **but** in case TextView2 visibility is gone I want to put TextView1 in the center of the layout.

Can someone help me with that?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView>
        android:id="@+id/TextView1”
        android:layout_width=“100dp”
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=“TextView”1
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart=“16dp"
        />

 <TextView>
        android:id="@+id/TextView2”
        android:layout_width=“100dp”
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=“TextView”1
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf=“parent”
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf=“@id/TextView1”
        android:layout_marginStart=“20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd“8dp"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the two *TextViews* in a [horizontal chain](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#Chains) with the chain style set to `spread_inside`. Now, when the right *TextView* is set to gone, the left *TextView* assumes the right constraint of the right *TextView* with a new margin set to `16dp` (`app:layout_goneMarginEnd="16dp"` ).

See [Margins when connected to a GONE widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#GoneMargin).

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="TextView1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/TextView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_goneMarginEnd="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView2"
        app:layout="@id/TextView1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TextView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: does both TextViews be fixed to the margin i set?

Comment: @Eitanos30 "gone" margins override regular margins for a widget when the other widget is "gone".

Answer (score 1):

> add or remove visibility property

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello2"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)** for this type of requirement

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:id="@+id/flexBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:background="@null"
    app:justifyContent="space_around">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/ContactTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

dependency -     `implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'`

Answer (score 0):

You should horizontal linear layout .

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
     <TextView>
        android:id="@+id/TextView1”
        android:layout_width=“match_parent”
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=“TextView”1
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
 android:layout_weight="0.5"
        
        />

 <TextView>
        android:id="@+id/TextView2”
        android:layout_width=“match_parent”
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=“TextView”1
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
 android:layout_weight="0.5"
       
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**like this** It's very simple then other answers

Comment: I think the value of the &layout_width* should be 0dp